# Is there anywhere to dive in the Mediterranean that's like the Red Sea?

Tags: scuba-diving, travelling

Have heard great things about diving in the Red Sea.  However,  Egypt's not the most stable and safe place to visit.

What are the alternative locations for diving in the European side of the Mediterranean where there's similar diving experience?

Thinking pretty fish,  abundant life and good visibility.  Have dived in France and Spain where these are "OK" but not the amazing colourful experience which the Red Sea's purported to be.  Oh and wrecks.  We all like diving in wrecks,  especially those covered in life.

---

Anyone have any suggestions for pretty fish in the Med?

---

Not many answers;  could we expand this question to:
Where is the 'prettiest' place in the Mediterranean to dive with lots of fish and interesting things to see?  Is it better in the west or east,  south or north?

Comment: The Red Sea borders more than just Egypt.  Just off the top of my head without looking at a map, there's Israel, Jordan, and Saudi Arabia at least.  I vaguely remember the diving near Aqaba, for example, is supposed to be spectacular, although I'm not a diver and I don't remember the source.

Comment: Lots of divers are still going to Egypt - most fly out, travel to the hotel, and only leave it to dive. If you want a good Mediterranean dive location though I've heard great things about the diving near Malta.

Comment: Egypt is a large country, not every region is really dangerous. Personally, I currently would not hesitate to stay in a tourist area like Sharm el Sheik, which is one of the best places for diving in the World. What I would avoid is taking an unaccompanied bus tour to the northern Sinai. If you fear terror attacks, you should also avoid places like London, Paris, Berlin, and Barcelona.

Comment: This isn't supposed to be a political discussion. However, security cleared people cannot go to certain places, Egypt and other Middle East counties are on that avoid/blocked list.  European countries aren't.  It's also a lot easier to go to European countries -- not to mention phone and data comma is cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

Malta, or more precisely Gozo, a small island right next to the main island, is a very well liked destination for divers within the EU. Friends of mine go there regularly.

Comment: If we want this question to stay clear off the "opinion-based" hammer, you will need to provide some more information than "well liked" and friends who go there regularly. What makes it an exceptional spot, how does it compare to the  Red Sea, whatever else is relevant for diving (not a diver). Just try to flesh it out please.

Comment: Malta's a great destination (aside from needing criminal liability insurance if you have an accident - [link](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-sussex-35350295) ).  However I'm not sure if the fish are as plentiful or 'pretty' as the Red Sea?  There's the benefit of some wrecks to dive on though.

Answer (score 1):

Port Cors, in the french riviera, is a national conservation park since 1963. The Gabinière is known for beeing one of the best dive site in mediterranea. You will find there groupers, barracudas, common dentexes and Gilt-head breams. If you are super lucky, you can see some seriolas and sunfishes.

What makes the sites so good is that the interdiction to feed the fishes leaved them to a savage state, while the almost daily presence of divers made the biggest fishes consider divers as others pacific fishes. They won't swim away seeing you, but they will if you get really too close (50cm to a meter).